# openvpn - forward network traffic from specific subnet to specific tun interface

Tags: routing, openvpn, openwrt

I am using a device running on openwrt (chaos_calmer 15.05)

I am trying to forward network traffic from two differents SSID to two different vps running openvpn

My setup is working with only one wifi / tun interface. It seems impossible to work that with the two VPN (openvpn client) at the same time.

I don't understand why :/ I think it's not a very complicate setup I hope somebody could help me here since you're network experts.

I think it's a routing issue but I am not sure. 
Anyone can help me to fix this please ?

**To simplify this, my setup looks like :**

```
eth0 (internet link) <===== tun0 <==== wifi-A
eth0 (internet link) <===== tun1 <==== wifi-B
```

**Note the following statements**

1. My openwrt device get the Internet link with the eth0 interface
   using DHCP
2. I created a bridge on my wlan0 interface to be able to broadcast two
   SSID : (wifi-a & wifi-b)
3. On wifi-a : a DHCP server is running pool 172.17.42.100-200 gw
   172.18.42.1
4. On wifi-b : a DHCP server is running pool 172.18.42.100-200 gw
   172.18.42.1
5. I have two VPS where I installed openvpn : PublicIP-1 & PublicIP-2
6. I run on my device two openvpn client to public-IP-1 (tun0) and to
   public-IP-2 (tun1)
7. Finally I nated wifi-a subnet to tun0 and wifi-b subnet to tun1 with the following iptables rules :

   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.42.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
       iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.17.42.0/24 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT iptables -A
       FORWARD -d 172.17.42.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i tun0 -j ACCEPT

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.42.0/24 -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
   iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.18.42.0/24 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT iptables -A
   FORWARD -d 172.18.42.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i tun1 -j ACCEPT
   ```

**Below my interface details :**

> eth0      inet addr:192.168.0.10 Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
> br-wifi-a inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:172.17.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
> br-wifi-b inet addr:172.18.42.1  Bcast:172.18.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
> tun0      inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
>
> tun1      inet addr:10.9.0.6  P-t-P:10.9.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255

**My route table :**

> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref
>   Use Iface
>
> default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>
> 10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
>   10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
>   10.9.0.1        10.9.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
>   10.9.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
>
> PublicIP-1     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
>
> PublicIP-2     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0   0 eth0
>
> 172.17.42.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-wred
>
> 172.22.42.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
>   192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

**Quick debug :**

> ping google.com -I tun1  PING google.fr (108.177.119.94): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 108.177.119.94: seq=0 ttl=43 time=29.665 ms
>
> ping google.com -I tun0  PING google.fr (108.177.119.94): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 108.177.119.94: seq=0 ttl=43 time=30.277 ms
>
> ping google.com -I eth0  PING google.fr (108.177.119.94): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 108.177.119.94: seq=0 ttl=42 time=17.860 ms ^C

Do you know where I am failing? 
Thanks for your help guys,

---

Additionally, I tried the following to add the add default gw for my tun interfaces :

```
echo "1 vpna" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "2 vpnb" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip rule add from 10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 table vpna
ip rule add from 10.9.0.0/24 dev tun1 table vpnb

ip route add default via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 table vpna
ip route add default via 10.9.0.5 dev tun1 table vpnb
```